# Multiprocess/multithread image analysis raspberry pi

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am trying to analyse the face of a driver with a raspberry pi while he's driving. I am using a Raspberry Pi 4 and I use mediapipe for face recognition with Python. I am trying to maximise my performance to analyse the maximum image per second. So I have 3 process, i am getting the image from the camera, i am analysing them with mediapipe and the final one is i am showing the image. My first question is: is it better to use multithreading for these 3 process or is it better to use multiprocessing. I was able to use multithreading, and I was able to get image at 30 fps (camera limitation) and to show them at this rate too. But, I was only analysing them at 13 fps. I tried to multiprocess but I am not able to figure out how. The first process of getting image is working but the other 2 are not working. [This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvnS7.png) is my class VideoGet, the first process to show you how I did my multiprocessing. And [this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmfN4.png) is my function that call every process together.

I was expecting that multiprocessing is the best thing to do.

I saw that maybe I should use pool instead of process but I am not sure.

Comment: Multithreading can be used for I/O (potentially for getting the images from multiple cameras at once, if that were a need), but for actual processing in parallel, you'd need multiprocessing.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yeah this is what I was thinking, do know you what I have not done correctly?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.